# cracking HMAC-SHA1 when the password and seed are inverted

Tags: sha, hmac, john-the-ripper

I happen to have a few hashes generated with code that did this (it has been changed to use a more "standard" bcrypt call):

```
$ python3
>>> import hmac
>>> hmac.new(b'The quick brown', b'123456', digestmod='sha1').hexdigest()
'c3b8986510970b778b26c42d954a93411f32f301'
```

i.e., it calculates `hmac.sha1(key=salt, message=password)` while john, by default calculates `hmac.sha1(key=password,message=salt)`

Is there a way to convince john the ripper to brute force `hmac.sha1(key=salt, message=password)`?

Comment: Why is this a problem? It's the same format. You just swapped the key and the message. What's the output of john when you try to crack the hash? You don't include anything we would need to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Why is your password method swapping the key and message?

Comment: Why is the code written that way ? I do not know. This is how it is.

Comment: Right ... well, if your code, which you can't change, reverses the key and the message, then `john` is not your tool. John brute forces the key.

Comment: Thanks schroeder, I updated the question to clarify it. Regarding the code, I already changed it (to use bcrypt) but I wanted to check the old passwords generated before I made the switch so, I cannot go back in time :/

Comment: FYI, that code happens to be not mine. I guess it was written that way precisely to make it harder to run a tool like john on the hashes. For future reference in case anyone cares: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/webapp2/blob/deb34447ef8927c940bed2d80c7eec75f9f01be8/webapp2_extras/security.py#L200

Comment: Hashcat could do it, I think..